# Rails - implementing subscriptions with Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, subscription

I am about to implement subscription billings with Stripe and what kind of makes think is the way how subscriptions works out.

I understand that I can specify all possible plans for subscriptions in Stripe's dashboard. In my app, when I send a Stripe request, Stripe will recognise the type of subscription plan based on the parameter "id" of the plan. That's clear.

But - is there any way to load all created subscription plans in Stripe's dashboard into my Rails app or do I need to create all subscription plans in Stripe's dashboard first and then to create a database table in my Rails table where I will store all information about subscription plans (so it would be - kind - data duplicating thing)?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with Stripe, I like to limit the amount of stuff I have to store on the Rails end. A lot of the time, I think you can get away with just recording a Stripe customer ID in your database along with each user. Then grab any info you need directly from Stripe via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#subscriptions).

That will definitely make some client requests take longer, but can hold you over while you get a better sense of what your app needs to do to have the best UX.

Then later you should look at a caching strategy that preemptively gets info you need from Stripe.

Comment: But this makes me think about recurring payments - I set up the frequency of subscription for one month. That means that every month Stripe system will automatically charge the customer's credit card - but will Stripe notify me when this happen? I would need to save the information about monthly charges to my Rails app's database, so based on that I could display to customers some extended functionality, when they paid.

Comment: You can get Stripe to notify your app when things happen via the [events API](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#event_types). So perhaps you can save the charge info locally when you get a notification from Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

**Some duplication may make typical queries and operations easier**. There are some things you **never** want to have on the Rails side (credit card numbers for instance). On the other side, subscription info such as plan name & possible trial period are handy to have locally, as you'll probably show/check those often ("Hi Martin, 5 days left on your Enterprise Plan trial").

If/when you start doing some duplication, I still advice you to **keep Stripe as the "master"** in the relation, ie, send the info to stripe then store it locally if successful. This should avoid the biggest duplication problem - being out of sync between the two systems.